# Create Windows Forms Control using Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reflection

I have an windows forms app which is creating controls based on string.

```
Type t = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, System.Windows.Forms");
```

But I am getting t as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the full name of the assembly (as this one is in the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache)), like this (it will also get back the good assembly even in framework 4):

```
Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code - based on `Activator.CreateInstance` method

```
var textBoxType = typeof(Control).Assembly.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.TextBox", true);
var textBox = Activator.CreateInstance(textBoxType);
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.80).aspx